# Sticky row buttons

Tags: html, css

I need to position a button for each row to the right side of a container that overflows horizontally, so that it is always on the right side of the container, not the end of the overflowed content. The content should scroll horizontally at the container level and the button should remain stationary.  The container is expandable too, so I cannot just set a left position. Can this be done without javascript?

See here:
https://codepen.io/nfknight/pen/jaQrrL

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid;
  overflow-x: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.button {
  width: 40px;
  height: 26px;
  background: grey;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}

ul {
  padding: 0
}

ul li {
  white-space: nowrap;
  list-style: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: yellow;
  margin: 15px 0;
  height: 26px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li>
      Row 1 Loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong content
      <div class="button">Btn 1</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      Row 2 short content
      <div class="button">Btn 2</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: you can try `positon:sticky` over the button, but this will work only for the first one

Comment: @TemaniAfif Right. Also, I need this to work in IE11, which does not support Sticky.

Comment: 'Container is expandable, too' - but, you will always have some fixed width, right? Otherwise, there will be no overflowing/scrolling, so...you have few 'constants'...

Comment: @sinisake Yes, the container in my real-world scenario has a draggable left-border, which the user can click&hold&drag to expand the container to a different width.

Comment: Ah, so... use javascript then... while you waiting for css solution, if there is any, you can easily make all work in js... :)